# Help me Identify this Photoshop action/style/effect

Tags: photoshop-effects, background, style-identification

Can any one help me to identify the following image effect or PS Action?

[image]

I need same BG color effect for my image.

Comment: It's a color blob with a white stroke on top. What exactly stops you from doing something similar and why do you think that's an existing known action?

Comment: Just a word to those down voting this question. The OP is probably a beginner who has made some incorrect assumptions as to how such an edit is made. It would be nice if we could just try to be a little more constructive here and take such opportunities to educate instead. To the OP. since you are new here, please take some time to review [our help pages on how to ask good questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an effect or an Action you can just apply with one click.

You can recreate something like this using a very simple arrangement of layers and use layer masking to remove the existing background of a photograph.

For example

[image]

To get the white overlay layer, I just used the magic wand to select the white pixels from your example image, created a new transparent layer and filled the selection with white, then I cleaned it up using a white brush and the eraser tool.

The most complex part of an edit like this is the background removal from the photograph. There are tutorials on youtube for that if you get stuck. Photoshop's ***Select and Mask*** functionality is what you need to search for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you share the PSD?

Comment: @Asmi No. I have answered your question with an easy way to achieve this. Please don't take advantage of users here by asking for free work or files. In any case, a PSD wouldn't really help you here, since the background removal of a photograph and creation of a layer mask would be different each time. Sorry about that.